# Sitecore CMS 6.2 - Fails to start up

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, webdev.webserver

My local Sitecore CMS 6.2.0.3322 has stopped working. I can no longer start up a local debug build and attach it to IIS or WebDev.WebServer20.exe (The VS2010 built in web server).

When I start with WebDev I'm seeing the following message appear in the debug output window a couple of times a second:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

If I run Process Monitor I'm seeing the following at approximately the same frequency.

```
Date & Time:    22/10/2010 11:10:37 a.m.
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  CreateFile
Result: NAME COLLISION
Path:   D:\Development\<project name>\Data\indexes\__system\write.lock
TID:    4948
Duration:   0.0000388
Desired Access: Generic Read/Write
Disposition:    Create
Options:    Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode:  Read
AllocationSize: 0
```

This will continue indefinitely without the site appearing. I suspect there is some form of deadlock occurring with the locking on the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleared my ..\Data\indexes\__system folder of all files and that fixed the problem.

Comment: That seems to have resolved the issue, thanks. I deleted all the files in the __system folder and the write.lock file was recreated. After stopping the web server processes the file stopped being recreated. I could then start the site again (segments.gen and segments_1 were the only files present after a successful start).